# Calculate table size in MySQL for one month in MB

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the growth in size of my table each month, considering the following table column in MySQL:

```
id (BIGINT) - Primary Key
Date (DateTime)
PageViews (INT)
ProductId (INT)
```

I have 2000 products on my shop. In the worst case scenario, every product will be viewed at least once per day. Each row represents a total PageViews per day for a specific product.

For example:

```
id = 6
DateTime = 02/12/2012
PageViews = 0
ProductId = 159
```

I want to calculate the total size of the table, or better to say, the growth in each month in KB or MB.

I know that there are various things that I should take into consideration and append to the calculation, but I am not aware of them and don't know how to compute them.

I intend to store my MySQL database on Xeround.com, with 50GB limit, so I need to make sure that when working with this schema I can rest assured that for the next 10 years, I won't have any problem :)

100 products will be added every year (roughly).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that the number of articles will remain more or less constant, but that there's a significant number of `update pageviews` per day on each of the records?  Because if that's the case, and there are no `insert`'s elsewhere the db size should remain rather constant.

Comment: The MySQL manual has a detailed section "Data Type Storage Requirements" which you can find at e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html if you google for "mysql field type sizes"

Comment: fvu, The number of products (not articles) will be around 2000, a growth of 100 products every year roughly. So inserts will be from time to time. I will need to create a query that checks if a product exists in a particular day, if not, insert it for a particular Day (DateTime)

Comment: @IdanShechter so there will be 1 record per product per day?  And pageviews is the number of views for that particular day?

Comment: @fvu, yes, that's right.

Comment: I think 50GB space for the database is more the enough. From you description I do not think you will ever run into limits. If you look at the worst case scenario you have described - we have 3000 products times 10 years times 365 days and we approximate 2KB per entry (which is overly bloated estimate) we still end up only with roughly 20Gb of data in 10 years in the worst possible scenario I can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this post and sorry guys but the comments are not very useful so decide to put an answer sharing what I have on one of my mySQL servers.

Not everyone tracks it's own DBs growth but is something not hard to implement.
The idea is simple capture table stats from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES on a weekly basis or depending on your needs.

First you create a table under a separate schema or any schema you prefer.

```
#
# Use stats_db for the default schema for this tool
#

USE stats_db;

#
# CREATE TABLE table_growth_history
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_growth_history` ;

CREATE TABLE `table_growth_history`
(
            `DATE` date not null
,
            `TABLE_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
,
            `TABLE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
,
            `ENGINE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
,
            `TABLE_ROWS` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
,
            `DATA_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
,
            `INDEX_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
,
            `DATA_FREE` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
,
            `AUTO_INCREMENT` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
,
            PRIMARY KEY(DATE,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME)
,
            KEY(TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME)
)
            ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then you add the insert script. You can use a cronjob too but I rather use MySQL EVENT scheduler:

```
#
# MySQL EVENT to add table stats for our new history table
#

DELIMITER ;;

CREATE
            EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `get_table_growth_history`
            ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
    STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
            DO BEGIN

INSERT INTO
                                            stats_db.table_growth_history
SELECT
       DATE(NOW())
            ,
       TABLE_SCHEMA
            ,
       TABLE_NAME
            ,
       ENGINE
            ,
       TABLE_ROWS
            ,
       DATA_LENGTH
            ,
       INDEX_LENGTH
            ,
       DATA_FREE
            ,
       AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM  
                            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

    END ;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

This will create an event for the next Monday and then every Monday will insert the data on the table. Changing the day according to your needs

Now what you want is a monthly report of table data growth you can use this query to get that once you complete 1 month of data capturing you can run it:

```
-- get dates

select distinct `date` from stats_db.table_growth_history order by `date` desc limit 1 INTO @this_week ;

set @last_month := @this_week - interval 4 week ;

-- pivot table
SET @report_monthly = NULL;
SET @report_monthly
  = CONCAT('select table_schema,table_name,
       max(case when date = @last_month then round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) end) as `last_month__',@last_month,'`,
       max(case when date = @this_week then round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) end) as `current_week__',@this_week,'`,
       (max(case when date = @this_week then round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) end) -
        max(case when date = @last_month then round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) end)
       ) as data_grow
from stats_db.table_growth_history t
where date in (@last_month , @this_week)
group by table_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @report_monthly;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Also you can change the time range according to your needs.

You will have the specs and size of all DBs in your server.